# Syntax question about Mysql

Tags: mysql

all.I'm a beginner of Mysql and I have one simple question here.
I want to insert a value to a specific row and column:

```
INSERT INTO users (doctor_id) VALUES('123') WHERE user_id='12';
```

But it says there's syntax error in this command, I don't know how to write it. Hope someone can help me~
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` is used to insert new rows, so you cannot use a `WHERE` clause with inserts. What you are probably looking for is `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE users set doctor_id = '123' where user_id = '12';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the UPDATE command.

```
UPDATE users SET doctor_id='123' WHERE user_id='12';
```